# Azure AD Multiple Reply URL

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am new into the Azure AD thing. While I was configuring SSO using SAML for one of the SaaS application with Azure AD they have provided with 5 reply URL's. How does azure AD knows after successful auth which uri to redirect. How is that managed?

Answer (score 1):

The reply URL is also referred to as the Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) URL. You can use the additional reply URL fields to specify multiple reply URLs. For example, you might need additional reply URLs for multiple subdomains. Or, for testing purposes you can specify multiple reply URLs (local host and public URLs) at one time.

You can get the detailed information about the restriction of the reply url from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url)

Generally after authentication it goes to the top most value.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but then what's the use of other 4 reply url's?

Comment: Does this mean, by configuring the indexes in ReplyURLs would help?